# Ubuntu sends a print request but printer does not print it?

Tags: drivers, printing, dell, hp

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell laptop and own a HP Laser 107a. I've installed the drivers and followed all the necessary steps and yet my computer sends a print request and my printer manages to ignore it, what might be the matter?
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling, messing with the printer settings, restarting, nothing works. Meanwhile my brother's laptop and his Windows OS works perfectly. It's all so tiresome.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do your logs say about the printing attempts?

Comment: "...and followed all the necessary steps" you need to outline what those steps were so we don't just repeat steps you have already taken. [edit] in to your question to provide better clarity

Comment: Have you looked at the cups setup at localhost:631 for your printer? What type of file are you trying to print and failing -- do all types fail? Some programs like evince will fail to print or even preview a postscript file, while qpdfview works fine.

Comment: Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) GUI at http://localhost:631 and use the command line tools `lpq` and `lpstat`. `lpstat -t` shows complete status